# emacs: how to get help on the word/function under cursor quickly?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I would like to see help pages when reading Emacs lisp codes. At times, I found I am in the situation of key in `C-h a` then type the name of function, then use apropos window to get to the help page. Wonder whether there is any better way of getting help on the word/phrase under the cursor?

Similarly, I have the same problem when using `S-k` to get manual pages.

Anyone knows a good way to handle this? Appreciated.

Comment: `C-h f` calls `describe function`, with the default option set to the word under the point.

Comment: What @Juancho said. (What command is `K` bound to?)

Comment: `K` is `S-k`. I updated the question.

Comment: in spacemacs `SPC h d f` is bound to `describe-function` and the function under the cursor will pop up first in the helm buffer

Answer (score 1):

Simply press `C-h f` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`C-h f` is describe-function and it defaults to the function at the current point.